# How to change languge in whole app using react-i18next in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

`I use local store to store languge but i dont'know how to change languge in whole app..

Here is my code,

import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

//where i put this method

const getLanguge = async () => {

```
// console.log("Heloooooooooooooooooosss")
var selectedLanguge = await getValue('language');
console.log("selected ITEM IS----------",selectedLanguge)
i18n.changeLanguage(selectedLanguge)
goToScreen();
```

};

`